# How can I change the Outlook icon back to yellow?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Starting in Office 2013, the Outlook icon changed color.  It is now annoyingly similar to the Word icon.  Can I get the old one back?

Comment: So your question is, how to change an application's icon?

Comment: No, I want an icon that fits the theme.

Comment: Firstly, downvoters have a duty to suggest improvements. Secondly, snarky comments are unwelcome. It's quite obvious here that @Jammin4CO is asking to change the icon of Outlook. Not of any application, specifically for Outlook. If there is a method that works for any application, that would do, but if it only works for Outlook, then that is fine too. Hence not the same question.

Answer (score 4):

Found an image on google, make the outside transparent(attached), then ran it through an ico converter online.  Make a shortcut on the desktop to Outlook.  Changed the icon to the one I made.  Found Outlook in the start menu and right click opened location.  Removed the old one and dragged in the one I made. TaDa!

[image: ClearedPng]